# Passing model from Kendo Mvc UI Grid to javascript function

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

Hi I'm using the Kendo MVC UI Grid. This is how it looks :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TegelCheckerModel>()
            .Name("Grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.TegelNaam);
                columns.Bound(p => p.TegelId).Sortable(false).Filterable(false).ClientTemplate("<span class='iconBtn raadplegen' onclick=\"javascript:showDetails('#= TegelNaam #')\" />").Title("");
            })
            .AutoBind(true)
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Filterable()
                    .Events(e => e.DataBound("gridDataBound "))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax() //Or .Server()
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetTegels", "TegelChecker")
            .Data("getAlvNummerAndVoorWie"))
            )
        )
```

There is a column which displays an image which is clickable.
At this moment I can pass the "Tegelnaam" from the row on which the image was clicked.
This works, but I want to pass the entire data of the row on which the item was clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: just pass the object `data` rather than just `TegelNaam` e.g. change it from **#= TegelNaam #** to `#= data #` obviously removing the quotes you have around this item

Comment: @DavidShorthose: changing it to data doesn't work. My html then looks like this : <span class="iconBtn raadplegen" onclick="javascript:showDetails([object Object])">

Comment: sorry. look at this answer I gave to someone yesterday as a possible solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165644/working-on-templates-for-coloums-in-kendo-grid/37167115#37167115

Comment: @DavidShorthose:  OK, now it seems to be working, kind of. Because when my page is loaded, I get in the dosomething function. But when I click, I don't get in it. And of course it shouldn't get in the function when my page is loading. This is my code now : columns.Bound(p => p.TegelId).Sortable(false).Filterable(false).ClientTemplate("<span class='iconBtn raadplegen' onclick=\"#=dosomething(data)\" />").Title("");

Comment: @DavidShorthose my genereated HTML looks like this : <span class="iconBtn raadplegen" onclick="undefined">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per my answer per a previous question I answered.

see link for a working example: http://dojo.telerik.com/OlALA

Modify your code from this:

```
.ClientTemplate("<span class='iconBtn raadplegen' onclick=\"javascript:showDetails('#= TegelNaam #')\" />")
```

to

```
.ClientTemplate("#=generateLink(data)#");
```

then the javascript function can do this:

```
 function generateLink(data)
  {
    var ret = '';

    if(data.StatusDesc === '' && data.newStatusDesc !== ''  && data.newStatusDesc !== null)
    {

      var linkElement = 'javscript:showDetails(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')'; 




      ret = "<span class='iconBtn raadplegen' onclick='" + linkElement + "'>" +                                  data.newStatusDesc + '</span>'; 

      console.log(ret); 

    }
    else 
    {
      ret = data.StatusDesc; 
    }




    return ret;
  }
```

the important bit here is `JSON.stringify(data)` this will encode the item as a string but will pass the object into the function correctly as shown by my mock up of your showDetails function:

```
 function showDetails(status){
      console.log(status); 
      console.log("Status is::"+ status);

      alert("Status is::" + status.newStatusDesc);
      return true; 
    }
```

I took me a bit to get this working (and trial an error) but this seems the most sensible way of doing it (in my opinion).